# Arduino Not Working as Intended when using barrel jack

Tags: arduino-uno, power

I am using an Arduino to control some mechanical components in a project I have. It controls a motor, two servos, a valve, and a compressor. When plugged into the computer, everything works fine and perfectly. However, when I power it through the barrel jack using our power supply, some weird things happen. First of all, our servos, which are powered through the Arduino, stop working. All the other components work except for them. Secondly, at the end of the code we have a 5 second delay. Using the computer it works fine. When powered with our supply the delay doesn't seem to happen at all. Any ideas?

Comment: You say the servos  are powered through the Arduino.   How are the  motor/valve/compressor powered?  What voltage do you read on the +5V line in the two different ways of powering the Arduino?  How's the +5V line look on a scope ?  Re the 5 second delay, if you have an LCD you can attach, display `millis()` before and after the `delay()` call

Comment: The motor, compressor, and valve are powered with our 12v battery, which is what the arduino runs on when not plugged in. I am not near my setup right now, so unfortunately I can't take those measurements until later, but I'll check them for sure.

Comment: You should not power servos *through* an Arduino.  Even if they have to use the same supply they should have their own wiring.  They should not use the Arduino's regulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem that you are facing is lack of power. It is likely that your power source cannot supply enough current or voltage to power the equipment AND the arduino. Try to get a power supply that has more amps.

Comment: This could be the case, but I doubt it. Our power supply is a large 12v battery. It looks like a car battery. I can try turning the motor off while the servos are running to see if that will fix it, but I have a feeling the battery should be powerful enough.

Comment: It could be that the 5V regulator on the Arduino is unable to provide enough power. Many USB ports now can provide many amps, but the 5V regulator is limited to 800mA.  How hot does the regulator get?

Comment: This might be the case. The regulator does get warm, so maybe we are reaching our current limit.

Comment: If there is a large amount of voltage, but you circuit is still drawing lots of current, then the circuit will remain unpowered.

Comment: @solver - that is untrue.  If the circuit is drawing sufficient current that it is "unpowered" then there will not be a large voltage either, rather it will have sagged below the "open circuit" rating of the regulator or supply.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I apologize for my lack of knowledge in this field.

Answer (score 1):

i agree with majenko, maybe you know how to fix it but if you do not know here is a site with good information to make you're own  5 volt Regulated source.

http://www.rakeshmondal.info/IC-7805-Voltage-Regulator

sorry for my bad english and good luck. :D

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently while powering a servo with a Arduino.
It did turn out to be power, our Arduino could only supply about 500ma and with sufficient speed or torque on the servo (a lot of times just the boot sequence) we would it the 500ma at peak, the effect however was baffling at first because when we hit the peak current the Arduino would reboot, this could account for you extra delay at the end.

For us the solution was simple bypass the Arduino when supplying current to the servos, in our case it as a 5v battery, you would probably need to drop the 12v to 6v in your case.